# What does $\text{div} (A \text{ grad }b)$ mean?

Tags: vector-analysis

I often see this term in my Applied Mathematics course.

If $\text{grad }b= \frac{\partial b}{\partial x}\hat{i}+\frac{\partial b}{\partial y}\hat{j}+\frac{\partial b}{\partial z}\hat{k}$, then would $\text{div}(A\text{ grad }b)$ mean $K(\frac{\partial^2 b}{\partial x^2}+\frac {\partial^2 b}{\partial y \partial x}+\frac {\partial^2 b}{\partial z \partial x})\hat{i}+...$?

Comment: $A$ should be $3\times 3$ matrix (might not be constant). div acts on vector fields and gives you a function. (So your last expression will not be correct. For example, if $A = I$, then div( grad $b)= \Delta b$.

Comment: What is $A$?  *that* is the question, leaving "to $B \ldots$" aside. . .

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean $\nabla\cdot\vec \nabla X$?

Assuming X is a scalar potential field like electrical potential [voltage unit], Gravitational potential [J/Kg] or fluid potential (I am from electrical engineering side, so not such good at mechanical examples),

Then, $\vec \nabla X$ gives you the vector field of that potential such as electrical field, gravity field or ...

and $\nabla\cdot\vec \nabla X$ gives you the source of that field such as density of electric charge at each point or mass density which causes Gravitational force or ...

Comment: Would it be correct to say $\text{ div}(A\text{ grad }X)=\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial z^2}$?

Comment: @algebraically_speaking:  then where did $A$ go?

Answer (score 0):

$\nabla \cdot (\vec A \nabla \phi)$ is a vector that can be written

$$\nabla \cdot (\vec A \nabla \phi)=\left(\hat x_i\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}\right)\cdot \left(\hat x_jA_j\hat x_k \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x_k}\right)=(\nabla \cdot \vec A)\nabla \phi +(\vec A \cdot \nabla)(\nabla \phi)$$

Comment: Um.... do you have any reference to that (I am not working on Applied math, but div($A$ grad $f$) is a quite standard notation in elliptic PDE which is not what you described)

Comment: @John I interpreted $A$ to be a vector field and $\phi$ to be a scalar field.  If so, then the divergence of the product of two vectors ($\vec a$ and $\nabla \phi$) is a vector given as in the post.  The development is effectively product rule differentiation applied to a tensor $\vec A \nabla \phi$.  Any text on vector and tensor analysis would likely suffice as a reference.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.

Comment: I am not saying that you write anything wrong mathematically, just that I have not seen any text interpreting that term as you described. So I suspect that this is not what the OP is looking for.